# How to test push notifications on amazon device farm

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm

I would like to test that if every model on device farm receives push notifications from gcm, but as you know, a device cannot receive a notification if google account is not added on a device, how can I add a google account automatically, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a test using a framework of your choice (Appium, Calabash, Espresso etc.) to add the Google account to the device. AWS Device Farm does not provide Google credentials so you must bring your own, sign-in using these credentials, and remove them when done.

However, please note that it is not recommended to add accounts in the AWS Device Farm public fleet. Please [review private devices](https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/pricing/) and reach out to us if they appear to be a possibility for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is sad that I cannot receive push notifications via GCM

Comment: To clarify, you can receive GCM notifications. You have to supply your own Google credentials and remove them when done.